# Regex / php code to check if a URL is a short URL

Tags: php, regex, url-shortener

I am attempting to create a php function which will check if the passes URL is a short URL. Something like this:

```
/**
 * Check if a URL is a short URL
 *
 * @param string $url
 * return bool
 */
function _is_short_url($url){
    // Code goes here
}
```

I know that a simpler and a sure shot way would be to check a 301 redirect, but this function aims at saving an external request just for checking. Neither should the function check against a list of URL shortners as that would be a less scale-able approach.

So are a few possible checks I was thinking:

1. Overall URL length - May be a max of 30 charecters
2. URL length after last '/' - May be a max of 10 characters
3. Number of '/' after protocol (http://) - Max 2
4. Max length of host

Any thoughts on a possible approach or a more exhaustive checklist for this?

**EDIT:** This function is just an attempt to save an external request, so its ok to return true for a non-short url (but a real short one). Post passing through this function, I would anyways expand all short URLs by checking 301 redirects. This is just to eliminate the obvious ones.

Comment: I don't think that you can decide this with just syntactically checking a URL. How would you for instance distinguish `http://w3.org/QA/` from `http://g.co/maps/varjz`? They both match all your criteria and are generally very similar.

Comment: As mentioned above, the function is an attempt to save an external request, so its fine to identify both as shorturls and try and expand both

Comment: What about if a legitimate vimeo url https://vimeo.com/152355040 , it will be detected as short url and it is not. Please help.

Comment: @karlosuccess in that case, you may want to adjust the qualifying overall URL length to 25 instead of 30 characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not recommend to use regex, as it will be too complex and difficult to understand. Here is a PHP code to check all your constraints:

```
function _is_short_url($url){
        // 1. Overall URL length - May be a max of 30 charecters
        if (strlen($url) > 30) return false;

        $parts = parse_url($url);

        // No query string & no fragment
        if ($parts["query"] || $parts["fragment"]) return false;

        $path = $parts["path"];
        $pathParts = explode("/", $path);

        // 3. Number of '/' after protocol (http://) - Max 2
        if (count($pathParts) > 2) return false;

        // 2. URL length after last '/' - May be a max of 10 characters
        $lastPath = array_pop($pathParts);
        if (strlen($lastPath) > 10) return false;

        // 4. Max length of host
        if (strlen($parts["host"]) > 10) return false;

        return true;
}
```

Comment: This is good, though I would not validate $parts["query"] as CMS systems tend to build in-system short URLs using internal ids (example WordPress)

Comment: @AkshayRaje Good point regarding query string. The code is a sample, it should be easy to modify it to match any additional criteria.

Comment: @Miroslav... I agree, rather I guess this is the best we can get without making a request

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small function which checks for all your requirements. I was able to check it without using a complex regex,... only preg_split. You should adapt it yourself easily.

```
<?php

var_dump(_isShortUrl('http://bit.ly/foo'));

function _isShortUrl($url)
{
    // Check for max URL length (30)
    if (strlen($url) > 30) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check, if there are more than two URL parts/slashes (5 splitted values)
    $parts = preg_split('/\//', $url);
    if (count($parts) > 5) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check for max host length (10)
    $host = $parts[2];
    if (strlen($host) > 10) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check for max length of last URL part (after last slash)
    $lastPart = array_pop($parts);
    if (strlen($lastPart) > 10) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I would test if the url shows a 301 redirect, and then test if the redirect redirects to another website:

```
function _is_short_url($url) {
   $options['http']['method'] = 'HEAD';
   stream_context_set_default($options); # don't fetch the full page
   $headers = get_headers($url,1);
   if ( isset($headers[0]) ) {
     if (strpos($headers[0],'301')!==false && isset($headers['Location'])) {
       $location = $headers['Location'];
       $url = parse_url($url);
       $location = parse_url($location);
       if ($url['host'] != $location['host'])
         return true;
     }
   }

   return false;
}

echo (int)_is_short_url('http://bit.ly/1GoNYa');
```

Comment: “[…] this function aims at saving an external request just for checking.”

Comment: Even tho i don't perfectly understand what the OP wants I believe my piece of code will get used by him, so I wouldn't delete it

Comment: If his intention is to really avoid additional requests, then I doubt that.

Comment: @yes123 The whole deal is to do a preliminary elimination check to get rid of obvious URLs before making requests. The idea is to use this function and pass all those URLs that return true through a generic URL expansion code / webservice

Comment: URL expansion code ? To get the redirect url you need anyway to make the first request

Comment: @yes123: if you use get_headers, ensure you do HEAD only. See [HEAD first with PHP Streams](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/head-first-with-php-streams/), scroll to the bottom of the post.

Comment: I my experience many webservers don't recognize HEAD well (they returns random 404s) but I tested this 4 years ago, maybe now those servers are updated

Comment: @yes123 How would I setup you function to return the full URL? I'm looking for a short URL to long URL function in PHP